# Examination of a very long sentence and classification of its component

Tags: grammar

I've got a really complicated sentence to me. If someone could figure out what it imply, please explain me. First of all these modifying clauses in the sentence below ("in which" , " by that" and "where") refers to which word(s) ? And in addition to that what is the predicate and subject of this sentence. Thank you in advance.

Here is the sentence:

> The conflict between royalists and parliamentarians unleashed a torrent of radical thinking in which the traditional image of society as a rigid hierarchy was displaced by that of a structure of equal rights where individuals exercise autonomy in crucial areas of their lives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative clause *in which &c* modifies *torrent of radical thinking*<sup>†</sup>: expressed as an independent clause this would be "the traditional image was displaced in this torrent of radical thinking".

---

<sup>† *You might alternatively argue that it is only* radical thinking *which is modified; it doesn't make much difference.*</sup>

---

The preposition phrase headed by *by* complements *displaced*, expressing the Agent of the passive verb: expressed in the active voice this would be "a structure of equal rights displaced the traditional image".

The relative clause introduced by *where* modifies *a structure of equal rights*: expressed as an independent clause this would be "in this structure individuals exercise autonomy".

As for the rest of your questions:

- The Subject is indeed *The conflict between royalists and parliamentarians*.
- English grammars which use the term 'Predicate' would say that **everything** from *unleashed* to the end of the sentence comprises the Predicate in this sentence; *unleashed* is the 'Verb' or 'Predicator'.
- Everything from *a torrent* to the end of the sentence is the Object. Its 'core' is the Noun Phrase *a torrent of radical thinking*, and what follows is a Relative Clause modifying the preceding Noun Phrase—which (as I said above) may be taken to be either the phrase headed by *torrent* or the phrase headed by *thinking*.
- In any case, there is **no** adverbial which modifies *unleashed*. *In crucial areas of their lives* may be taken as an adverbial modifying the clause headed by *exercise*. Traditional grammar might classify the Preposition Phrase headed by *by* as an adverbial modifying *displaced*; I would classify it as an agentive **complement** of *displaced* licensed by the passive construction.

Comment: Thank you for your precious answer. Can I say that, Subject, object, redictae and adverb is following:

Subject: The conlfict between royalist and parlamentarians.

Object: a torrent of radical thinking in which the traditional image of society as a rigind hierarchy was displaced by.

Predictae: unleashed.

Adverb: that of a structure of ewual rights where individuals exercise autonomy in crucial areas of their lives.

Comment: @UfukCaglayan I've made some additions to address these matters.